# The delay functionality from redux saga is not working

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

Im trying to use the delay functionality but I get an error that delay is not a function.

Straight from the docs:

```js
import { race, call, put, delay } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* fetchPostsWithTimeout() {
  const {posts, timeout} = yield race({
    posts: call(fetchApi, '/posts'),
    timeout: delay(1000)
  })

  if (posts)
    yield put({type: 'POSTS_RECEIVED', posts})
  else
    yield put({type: 'TIMEOUT_ERROR'})
}
```

Comment: The documentation example doesn't help us to help you. Please, share your relevant piece of code.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suspect the reason for this is because the docs were recently updated for redux-saga `v1.0.0`. This is important because previously (in 0.x versions you are probably using) it wasn't effect but just a helper.

**In the 0.x version you should import it as:**

`import {delay} from 'redux-saga'`

This delay function will return a promise.

**In the 1.0.0 version you can use it as mentioned in the docs.**

`import {delay} from 'redux-saga/effects'`

This delay is an effect creator and will return an effect object.

For more info about the v1 release see https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: ill give it a shot.